# Issue with Spring Cloud Dataflow and Mysql 5.6

Tags: spring, flyway, spring-cloud-dataflow, mysql-5.6

I have the following problem when trying to start a SCDF server connected to Mysql 5.6.

Using the following command to start a SCDF server connected to a mysql database (version 5.6):

`java -jar spring-cloud-dataflow-server-2.9.0-RC1.jar --spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database --spring.datasource.username=username --spring.datasource.password=password --spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver`

I get this error trying to start the server:

`Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.internal.license.FlywayEditionUpgradeRequiredException: Flyway Teams Edition or MySQL upgrade required: MySQL 5.6 is no longer supported by Flyway Community Edition`

Looking for solutions online I tried to use this command:

`java -jar spring-cloud-dataflow-server-2.9.0-RC1.jar --spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jacad31_database --spring.datasource.username= --spring.datasource.password= --spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver --spring.flyway.enabled=false --spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always`

After that the server starts but then this error happens when I try to open the SCDF dashboard:

`Caused by: org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.MariaDbSqlException: Table 'database.app_registration' doesn't exist`

I tried to add this startup command but the error continues:

`--spring.datasource.schema=classpath*:/org/springframework/cloud/dataflow/server/db/migration/mysql/V1__INITIAL_SETUP.sql`

I think this happens because flyway is responsible for creating server configuration files on startup but since I'm not using flyway the config tables are not created. My question is: how can I create this tables on my database without flyway?

Comment: This is a known issue with the MySQL service broker. There are no plans to upgrade the MySQL version for CF as far as we know.

Answer (score 1):

[Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/2.9.2/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-local-rdbms-schema) are pointing to schema files in [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/tree/2.9.x/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-core/src/main/resources/schemas). You can create tables either manually or bootstrap those via server without flyway.